# Python JSON request body construction

Tags: python, json, post

I'm having a headache trying to construct a JSON body for a POST request.
When the body is fixed and defined like this:

```
body_works = {"databaseName": "admin",  "username": "foo", "password" : "bar",  "roles": [{"databaseName": "foo-db", "roleName": "readWrite"}]}
```

...the request below works fine:

```
response = requests.post(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, json = body_works)
```

The problem comes up in the non-trivial case where the "username" and "password" parameters inside the body are string variables.

How must I construct the body then?

I have tried this, using single quotes to enclose double quotes:

```
body = '{"databaseName": "admin",  "username": "' +  username + '", "password": "' + password + '",  "roles": [{"databaseName": "' + username +'", "roleName": "readWrite"}]}'
```

When I print(%s) the body_works variable above, it prints with single quotes. When I print the body I construct, it prints with double quotes, and the request fails.

Comment: Why dont use a dict then json.dumps(dict)

Comment: The first example is not JSON, but a python `dict`.

Comment: @Wonka I don't know how. I'm trying to build on the trivial case where the entire body is fixed. If you can provide the two commands (body setting and request syntax), I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @ivvija  Are you referring to the "body_works"? OK, understood, but in any case the request works that way. Except it's a trivial case.

Comment: What do you mean by "string variables"? Can you give an example "where the "username" and "password" parameters inside the body are string variables."? Do you just mean variables that happen to contain strings?

Comment: Have you tried simply `body_works = {"databaseName": "admin",  "username": username, "password" : password,  "roles": [{"databaseName": "foo-db", "roleName": "readWrite"}]}`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to differentiate between JSON string and Python dicts. What you provided in the first line is a Python dict, while requests expects a json. First example works, because it just so happens that it doesn't use anything that sets those 2 formats apart. As soon as you introduce variables, it becomes clear we're dealing with a Python dict. You can convert it using `json.dumps()` (inverse operation is `json.loads()`)

```
import requests, json

body_works = {"databaseName": "admin",  "username": username, "password" : password,  "roles": [{"databaseName": username, "roleName": "readWrite"}]}
response = requests.post(url, auth=auth, headers=headers, json = json.dumps(body_works))
```

Comment: But the requests documentation states: "If you need that header set and you don’t want to encode the dict yourself, you can also pass it directly using the json parameter (added in version 2.4.2) and it will be encoded automatically:" and then gives an example with `request.pot(url, json=payload)`, where `payload` is a dict.

Comment: I ended up creating a dict (starting with { } and adding stuff) and passed it in the request with json=dict. It worked fine.